# Alt and Ctrl keys not working with keyboard.is_pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

So simply, I was trying to create a code that when you press certain buttons, it writes out whatever you put into the Tk input. I was trying to make a hotkey with alt and another letter but whenever I use alt or ctrl, the function does not work and opens up random applications on my screen. everything works fine with keys like shift + a for example, but outputs it all in capitals because of the use of shift. The part where I write the Hotkeys is where all the Hotkey variables are

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard, pyautogui
import os
import sys
import tkinter.messagebox
import time

root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.iconbitmap('Logo.ico')
root.title(" ")
root.geometry("170x300")
Canvas(root, width=170, height=300)

hotkey1 = "alt + q"
hotkey2 = "alt + w"
hotkey3 = "alt + e"
hotkey4 = "alt + r"

Label(root, text="MacMaker").place(x = 50)
Label(root, text="Type in Macros below:").place(x = 27, y = 21)
Label(root, text="F4:").place(x = 5, y = 48)
Label(root, text="F7:").place(x = 5, y = 78)
Label(root, text="F8:").place(x = 5, y = 108)
Label(root, text="F9:").place(x = 5, y = 138)

thing1 = Entry(width=20)
thing1.place(x = 35, y = 50)
thing2 = Entry(width=20)
thing2.place(x = 35, y = 80)
thing3 = Entry(width=20)
thing3.place(x = 35, y = 110)
thing4 = Entry(width=20)
thing4.place(x = 35, y = 140)


def my_mainloop():
    macro1 = thing1.get()
    macro2 = thing2.get()
    macro3 = thing3.get()
    macro4 = thing4.get()
    if keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey1):
        pyautogui.typewrite(macro1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey2):
        pyautogui.typewrite(macro2)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey3):
        pyautogui.typewrite(macro3)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey4):
        pyautogui.typewrite(macro4)
    root.after(1, my_mainloop)  

root.after(1, my_mainloop)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.is_pressed), it looks like it should be:

```
hotkey1 = "alt+q"
hotkey2 = "alt+w"
hotkey3 = "alt+e"
hotkey4 = "alt+r"
```

*without the spaces*

Comment: I had the gaps with shift and it worked. I tried it without the gaps anyway and it still doesn't seem to work.